# How do I center this picture for hanging?

Tags: bathroom, walls, interior

I have a panoramic picture I’d like to hang in a bathroom. It’s across from the stool. It’s 3’ wide and 1’ tall.

Do I center it on the midline of the **wall**, or on the midline of the **HVAC vent**?

[image]

Comment: This question is unclear. Midline or midline?

Comment: What is the "midline" of the wall?  "*How do I center this picture for hanging?*" I say centered will center it  and at eye level.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg ope, sorry, meant midline of the wall or midline of the HVAC vent.

Comment: The window and the vent seem to be the same distance from the ceiling. I would vote to have the top of the picture line up along the same distance. If it looks wrong, what about a series of images above the vent and picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is personal preference, it is your bathroom  (*presumably.*) If so, you get to decide.

My personal preference is to center it on the wall, side to side,  under the vent at eye level. (*pretend the vent is not there, where would you put it?*)